# Linux find everything that is minified?

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I need a `find` parameter that would:

1. list all that are not in folder `./bootstrap`
2. exclude files that end in `.js`, but not in `.min.js`
3. exclude files that end in `.css`, but not in `.min.css`

Preferably in a unique command.

I've been looking at `-prune` and `-regex`, but none seem to work. I'm using this to feed into a `zip` command to compress everything as part of my build process.

Comment: What have u tried so far? We won' t code u a complete script. That' s not StackOverflow.

Comment: Does it have to be only with `find`?  How about using `grep` to filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
find . ! \( -name bootstrap -prune -o -name '*.js' ! -name '*.min.js' -o -name '*.css' ! -name '*.min.css' \)
```

If you only want to keep the files, add `-type f` at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work:

```
find . \( -iname "*.js" -or -iname "*.css" \) -not -iname "*.min.js" -not -iname "*.min.css" | grep -v '^\./bootstrap'
```

You can also do it with `find`'s `-prune` flag, but I think the syntax is way more convoluted than a simple `grep`.

Also note that I'm using `-iname` instead of `-name` - this makes the strings case-insensitive, which is usually what I do, in case my source tree has files from Windows in it, but feel free to use whichever suits your situation better.

Comment: Never thought of combining grep with find. Thanks.

Comment: This finds all and only .js and .css files, the exact oposite of #1, #2 and #3. Easy to fix. You should have a website on your profile.